# Salesforce.com report works OK in Chrome & Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: reporting, browser

I have a rather large summary report (about 4,300 total rows) in Salesforce.com that renders OK when run in Chrome, but when I attempt to run the same report in Internet Explorer 8.0, the browser becomes unresponsive.  I get no error message, IE just locks up.  Other, smaller reports run fine in IE.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or have a solution (**other than "Don't use IE"**).  Unfortunately our corporate standard is IE 8, so that's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring14 release notes make a specific note that ["The Compatibility View feature in Internet Explorer isn’t supported." (see page 30)](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf)

Can you make sure you have that disabled? I have seen it cause issues in other areas of salesforce.

Comment: Also, IE8 is on its way out the door. Salesforce recommends v10 if you can. v8 has a very slow JS engine.

Comment: @sfdcfox true. Most of what I work on explicitly desupports IE8. It's a poor choice even if you are going to run IE, but it technically is supported by SFDC for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

So evidently there is a bug if you have floating headers and a large number of groupings that causes it to not complete if using IE8.  A link to the reported issue and potential fixes can also be found at the link below.

https://success.salesforce.com/apex/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4PUAA0